# How to search across multiple Google Drive accounts?

Tags: google-drive

I use Google Drive with multiple accounts. How can I search for something across all of these accounts?

Comment: Have not tried this but there seems to be a product that does what you are asking: https://www.cloudfuze.com/access-google-drive-multiple-accounts/

Comment: This remains a huge weakness of Gdrive imo.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Share the all the files and folders from the accounts that holds the files with the account that you want to use for searching.

## How to

2. Use a folder as a "Master Archive", so its's sharing settings will be propagated to all the files and folders added or moved to it.

   1. Select one of your account as the "master account"
   2. Create a folder to be used as a "Master Archive" in your "master account" and share it with editor access to your other account.
   3. At each account move the "Master archive" of step [2] to "My Unit"
   4. Move or add your files and folders to the "Master archive" of step [2].

## Alternatives

1. Use a third-party app.

## References

- [How to share - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en)
- [Search your files - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en)
- [Shared with me - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375057?hl=en)